# How to style the Google Play Services error on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

When using the new Google Maps V2 API on Android, the user will see an error message if their device does not have the Google Play (Services) app installed. I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow override the style of this error message to make it less jarring and fit the app styling more appropriately.

This is what the error looks like:

[image: This app won't run unless you update Google Play services.]

Comment: How are you bringing that up? The result from `getErrorDialog()` is not nearly as jarring. That being said, I have not seen anything documented for affecting this portion of the UI.

Comment: I just have the map fragment embedded in an XML layout. It displays this content if the play services are missing. I didn't know about the error dialog option! That seems like a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go the `getErrorDialog()` route. This whole portion of the Maps V2 experience sucks, but `getErrorDialog()` seemed to me to suck the least. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After doing some investigating, I determined that the best solution was to manually check for the presence of the Google Play Services library and display a custom error dialog or error layout. There are some utility methods in [`GooglePlayServicesUtil`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html) that make this fairly straightforward.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int statusCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (statusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        // Continue with your regular activity/fragment configuration.
    } else {
        // Hide the map fragment so the default error message is not
        // visible.    
        findViewById(R.id.map).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Show a custom error message
        showErrorMessage(statusCode);
    }
}

private void showErrorMessage(final int statusCode) {
    // I've outlined two solutions below. Pick which one works best for
    // you and remove the if-block.
    boolean showDialog = false;

    if (showDialog) {
        // This is the easiest method and simply displays a pre-configured
        // error dialog
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode, this, 0).show();
    } else {
        // Show a completely custom layout
        findViewById(R.id.error).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Wire up the button to install the missing library
        Button errorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.error_button);
        errorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // Perform the correct action for the given status
                    // code!
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorPendingIntent(
                            statusCode, getActivity(), 0).send();
                } catch (CanceledException e1) {
                    // Pass
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to set suitable text for button?

Comment: To show the alert, is better to check first `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(statusCode)`

Answer (score 2):

Twadington's answer was great. However, when I tried to use it, but the method was deprecated. So, after much research, I created a function called `isPlayServicesAvailable()` that you can use to check before using any feature that uses Play Services. It will automatically create dialogs based on error and also link to the play store if the issue is resolvable.

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Activity activity) {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
                googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, status, 0, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
            else {Toast.makeText(this, "This app can not run on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I hope it will save much of your precious time. 
P.S.- I have just started answering on StackOverflow, do let me know your suggestions about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

- `GooglePlayServiceUtil` is deprecated. Look at [`GoogleApiAvailability`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) for latest interfaces.
- Prefer using the provided `DialogFragment` instead of the error `AlertDialog` directly, so that it can be properly managed by the activity.

  ```
  public static boolean checkPlayServices(FragmentActivity activity) {
      GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
      int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);

      if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
              // "user resolvable" means Google Play is available to download the last version of Play Services APK
              // This will open Google dialog fragment displaying the proper message depending on "resultCode"
              googleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
          } else {
              // Should not happen. This device does not support Play Services.
              // Let's show an ultimate warning.
              MyCustomPlayServicesErrorDialogFragment playServicesErrorDialog = new MyCustomPlayServicesErrorDialogFragment();
              playServicesErrorDialog.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), TAG);
          }
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```